# [Possible Pyqtgraph bug]PyQt5/Pyqtgraph Get Numpy Array for What is Currently on the Viewbox

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

In this post, let us consider a situation very similar to [PyQt5/Pyqtgraph Get Numpy Array for What is Currently on the Scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73419445/pyqt5-pyqtgraph-get-numpy-array-for-what-is-currently-on-the-scene). With the same image as in the linked post, the following code runs:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from pyqtgraph.exporters import ImageExporter

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.button = QPushButton("Save")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.get_numpy_array)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        image = asarray(Image.open(image_directory))
        self.graphics = Graphics(image)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.graphics)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def get_numpy_array(self):
        # Export current viewvbox into bytes
        exporter = ImageExporter(self.graphics.viewbox)
        data = exporter.export(toBytes=True)

        # Convert QIMage into RGB image
        input_img = data.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGB888)
        width = input_img.width()
        height = input_img.height()
        # Get pointer to data
        ptr = input_img.bits()
        ptr.setsize(input_img.byteCount())
        # Create numpy array from data
        arr = np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 3)
        # This part transforms array back to image
        img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGB')
        img.save("./slice.png")
        
        print(arr.shape)
        return arr


class Graphics(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super().__init__()
        layout = self.addLayout()
        self.image = image
        self.shape = image.shape
        self.viewbox = layout.addViewBox(lockAspect=True)
        
        self.left_image_item = pg.ImageItem(image)
        self.right_image_item = pg.ImageItem(image)
        self.viewbox.addItem(self.left_image_item)
        self.viewbox.setLimits(minXRange=0,
                               minYRange=0,
                               maxXRange=self.shape[0],
                               maxYRange=self.shape[1])
        
        self.another_viewbox = layout.addViewBox(lockAspect=True)
        self.another_viewbox.addItem(self.right_image_item)

        x, h = 300, 50
        polyline = pg.PolyLineROI(
            [[x, x], [x + h, x], [x + h, x + h], [x, x + h]], pen=pg.mkPen("b", width=5), closed=True, rotatable=False)
        self.viewbox.addItem(polyline)
        
        x, h = 100, 50
        ellipse = pg.EllipseROI(
            pos=[x, x], size=[x + h, x], pen=pg.mkPen("r", width=5), rotatable=False)
        self.another_viewbox.addItem(ellipse)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    
    app.exec()
```

As it can be seen, this is precisely the solution proposed by Domarm with only one modification: there is another viewbox. Running will give something like:

[image]

---

My goal remains the same as in the linked post: read what is currently on the scene for the (left) `viewbox` without caring what is going on the (right) `another_viewbox`. (Again, I added ROIs just to emphasize we want what is currently on the scene and they have nothing to do with the problem.) Notice that, in this case, the proposed solution no longer works.

Questions:

1. I thought `ImageExporter` created in this way should only do everything subject to the first viewbox. The second viewbox should not matter. What went wrong?
2. How to fix the situation ?

---

Updates:

By typing `conda list` in my anaconda prompt, I get to know that I am using python `3.8.13`, pyqt `5.15.7`, and pyqtgraph `0.12.4`. If I use the same image then the error message is always the same no matter how the image or roi was moved:

[image]

However, if I add the following command in `get_numpy_array`:

```
self.label = QLabel()
pixmap = QPixmap(input_img)
self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
self.label.show()
```

Then, despite the error described above, a window will show up and give the correct image. This shows `input_img` is indeed the `QImage` I want and the problem lies within the conversion from `QImage` to `numpy`.

---

It turns out that if I just write the following:

```
def get_numpy_array(self):
        # Export current viewvbox into bytes
        exporter = ImageExporter(self.graphics.viewbox)
        data = exporter.export(toBytes=True)
        
        # Convert QIMage into RGB image
        input_img = data.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGB888)
        input_img.save("./slice.png")
```

Then the image is saved regardless of the number of viewboxes I have. If I read the saved I will get a numpy array. So the problem is resolved. But I will still accept any answer explaining why the above code was not working or whether this is a bug.

Comment: I've tried your code. For me `exporter = ImageExporter(self.graphics.viewbox)` returns only the left image and `exporter = ImageExporter(self.graphics.another_viewbox)` returns only right image. From your description, it seems that behavior is exactly what you want  ` read what is currently on the scene for the (left) viewbox without caring what is going on the (right)`. If that's not the case for you, please post version of python and pyqtgraph you're using. Also you can try most recent pyqtgraph version 0.12.4.

Comment: I have updated the post to contain the version information and error message. What version of python are you using?

Comment: It is resolved. See the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with `Qimage.Format888` (basically RGB array of shape RxGxB). Using different format RGBA888 (RxGxBxA) solves the issue. Reshaping using fourth dimension (A) `np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 4)` and converting image back `img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGBA')` works just fine.

This is only necessary if you need `np.array`. If you just want to save a picture, you can can save `data` already using `data.save("./slice.png")`. No need for `input_img = data.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGB888)`, since `data` is already a `QImage`.

So the final code for `get_numpy_array` is:

```
def get_numpy_array(self):
    # Export current viewvbox into bytes
    exporter = ImageExporter(self.graphics.viewbox)
    data = exporter.export(toBytes=True)
    # Convert QIMage into RGB image
    input_img = data.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGBA8888)
    width = input_img.width()
    height = input_img.height()
    # Get pointer to data
    ptr = input_img.bits()
    ptr.setsize(input_img.byteCount())
    # Create numpy array from data
    arr = np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 4)
    # This part transforms array back to image
    img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGBA')
    img.save("./slice.png")
    return arr
```